# My css files are not running inside my .blade.php file

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm doing a little website for me with Laravel 8.0.

Inside `home.blade.php`, I have this : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/header.css') }}">`
But when I go to my browser, no css in my page. Inside the developper tools, it says `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/css/header_site.css">`.

I have all my css inside the `public/assets/css` folder.

I also used the VirtualHost inside `httpd-vhosts.conf` where I do `DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/my-project/public"`.

Cordially

Comment: try with `href="{{ asset('assets/css/header.css')`

Comment: Still not working. I also tried with `URL::` and also with `public/assets/css/header.css` What trigger me is that when I go to the developper tools, there path is `http://localhost/css/header_site.css` and that's wrong.

Comment: give the full url for testing purposes. `http://localhost/assets/css/header_site.css` Also see if this url produces the css file in the browser.

Comment: Also, by public/asset.. you mean in the public folder right? Not the storage/public/assets? Coz, if it's storage make sure you have established the symlink.

Comment: Well, right now my URL when I go to the developper tools its `http://localhost/css/header_site.css` but when I try this `http://localhost/assets/css/header_site.css`, it produce the css file in the browser.The full URL is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/header_site.css') }}"> ` And yes, its in the public folder at the top of my project `public/assets/css`

Comment: Well then, why dont you try configuring the assets url in the .env file. `ASSET_URL=http://localhost/assets/`. Then do `{{asset('css/header.css')}}`. See if it changes anything,

Comment: So I tried to add `assets` like that `{{ asset('assets/css/header_site.css') }}` but still not working. In the developper tools, it shows `{{ asset('css/header_site.css') }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try configuring the assets url in the `.env` file. `ASSET_URL=http://localhost/assets/`. Then do `{{asset('css/header.css')}}`